how to insert multiple data in a bd using threads with java?
I must make a program that obtains data from a DB and insert what the query returns into another table in another DB, the records that that table contains are millions, in one hour there are approximately 40 million, it is a historical table, I did The following as an example handling only 1 million data, I made a select with a limit of 100 thousand, to obtain the data as per pages and it works, but I only did it to test how it would be and it works for me, but in reality it is that With that amount of records that I mention, there comes a point where Java sends an error from the heap memory and it stays there without finishing, I already adjusted that parameter to change the memory but it still dies.
Is it possible to do it using threads?
and how would it be? or what other alternatives can I use?
this is my code and  it works, but when is more data, send error of memory
public void leerDatos() throws IOException {
        String user = "postgres";
        String pss = "admin123";
        
        empleadoList = new ArrayList<>();
        Empleados empleado = null;
        ResultSet result = null;
        PreparedStatement stm = null;
        Connection connect = null;
        
        final int pageSize = 100000;
        int offset = 0;
        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bd_test", user, pss);
            PreparedStatement stmCount = connect.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) from empleados");
            ResultSet resultCount = stmCount.executeQuery();
            int records = 0;
            
            while (resultCount.next()) {
                records = resultCount.getInt(1);
            }
        
            while (offset < records) {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM empleados ORDER BY id LIMIT ? OFFSET ?";
                stm = connect.prepareStatement(query);
                stm.setInt(1, pageSize);
                stm.setInt(2, offset);
                result = stm.executeQuery();
                while (result.next()) {
                    empleado = new Empleados();
                    empleado.setNombre(result.getString("nombre"));
                    empleado.setApellido(result.getString("apellido"));
                    empleado.setSalario(result.getString("salario"));
                    empleadoList.add(empleado);
                }
                offset += pageSize;
               
            }
            if (!empleadoList.isEmpty()) {
                
                insertarDatos(empleadoList);
            }
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("SQL Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (result != null) {
                    result.close();
                }
                if (stm != null) {
                    stm.close();
                }
                if (connect != null) {
                    connect.close();
                }
                
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println("SQL Error en cierre: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


You don't need threading. You need to stop using an in memory list.

What can I use instead of the list? Can yo explain me please

From the code in your question I understand that you are using PostgreSQL database. PostgreSQL has tools for exporting and importing data. I assume that those tools would be better than writing a Java program to do the same.

To be more precise you probably could use a list with a lot less records per page to use less memory. You are not giving enough details of why you are using such a big number of records per page, or how paging actually helps your use case, or what are you really trying to achieve and what is the actual error.

Just use bulk-data export and import via Postgres commands COPY FROM & COPY TO. See manual. No need for Java here.

you can perform the loading of millions of data using Multithreading. You can use CompletableFuture for fetching and loading of data from DB. Here are the steps that you can follow :

Create ThreadPoolExecutor which manages the threads according to the volume of data, DB Connections, and CPU core size. In the below link you can check
the implementation.
https://howtodoinjava.com/java/multi-threading/how-to-use-blockingqueue-and-threadpoolexecutor-in-java/

you can add either of these two - pagination concepts or a scheduler that
picks a certain amount of data every time and processes the same.

You can use CompletableFuture with runAsync or supplyAsync.
The logic of using below will first fetch data from DB using
CompletableFuture and then save it into another DB using another call.
result.stream().map(str -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(()->
writeResultToS3(str),customPool)).collect(Collectors.toList());


